# Was the block comment designed to enable/disable blocks using a single character?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, comments, language-design

Observe the following block of code:

```
//*
 ... code block ...
//*/
```

It can be enabled/disabled using just the first slash.

```
/*
 ... code block ...
//*/
```

Was this by design, or is it a happy coincidence?
There doesn't seem to be any history on the matter.

Comment: That's a clever trick, but it makes it hard to tell which way it is set without good syntax-highlighting.

Comment: @stark: Yes, it's a clever trick. I've learned over the years that "clever" is often a bad thing.

Comment: Indeed - the clever trick should instead be a run-of-the-mill preprocessor directive.

Comment: I agree.  `#if 0` or `#if 1` is also only one character difference

Comment: @KeithThompson In production/publicly shared code, clever is a bad thing. In single-use/private code, I think it might be appropriate.

Comment: @stark: But `0` and `1` are easier to tell apart at a glance. Or you can just insert `//` at the beginning of every line that you want to comment out (which should be easy to do in any decent editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can say it was *designed* this way. Block comments were introduced in C way before single-line comments appeared - and this is what your code ends up being after you add another slash.

I'd rather call it a happy coincidence.

Comment: Yes, but `//` comments go back to BCPL, C's grandparent language. BCPL didn't have `/* ... */` comments; those come from PL/I. I suspect that C++ was the first language to support both.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It's hard to say if it's designed or a 'happy coincidence'.  It appears designed to me (but I think that would also depend on what's between the comment lines).</strike>

It appears that I misunderstood the question - I thought the OP came across some code with a comment formatted in that fashion and wondered if the person who wrote it intended for it to be enabled/disabled with a single character change.

As far as whether the C comment styles were designed to allow such behavior, I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".  The C99 Standard Rationale document makes no mention of the technique, which I'd think would be in the rationale if the comments were designed to enable it.  In fact the rationale specifically says that comments should not be used to disable code and that preprocessor mechanisms should be used instead.

Also if the comment syntax was designed to permit this bit of cleverness (and I do think it's clever), I believe that someone would have written about it before.  This is the first time that I have seen this particular technique of mixing comment styles to enable/disable blocks of code.

I have very occasionally done something similar by design for certain types of debugging (I do not advocate committing the following construct to version control - use prepossessing with `#if` or similar instead if you really need to select between one of two or more alternatives):

```
int x = /**/ 123 /*/ 456 /**/;
```

As written above, `123` will be active and `456` will be commented out.

Removing one of the first two `'*'` characters will make `123` inactive and `456` active.

Answer (score 1):

The `/* */` comments originate with C and were adopted with C++. C++ then added `//` for single line comments.
What you show is a currious example of those two types of comments interacting. I doubt anyone thought of that when writing the standard - and if they did they probably thought "just don't do that".